# Return ScanPage Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, barcode-scanner

I have a button with open a scan (as a modal). When I scan a QRCode i have a display alert with 2 buttons. When I click on "no" I want to return on my scan and not in my page (listPeoplePage).

So I have a button ScanClicked (when I open the scan)

```
 private async Task BtnScanClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Ouverture de la page de scan
        scanPage = DependencyService.Get<IScanPage>(); // new ZXingScannerPage();

        if (scanPage.scannerPage.IsScanning)
            return;

        scanPage.scannerPage.IsScanning = true;
        if (scanPage.scannerPage.Parent == null)
        {
            // On affiche la page
            await Navigation.PushModalAsync(scanPage.scannerPage); //.PushAsync(scanPage.scannerPage);
        }

        // Le check des résultats
        scanPage.scannerPage.OnScanResult += (result) =>
        {
            // Pour éviter de le faire tant que le client n'a pas validé
            if (scanPage.scannerPage.IsScanning == false)
                return;

            // On stoppe le scan
            scanPage.scannerPage.IsScanning = false;

            // On retire la page et on montre le résultat
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
            {

                // On essaye de récupérer le code IdA09 si il existe et on appelle le WS
                string paramA09 = getParameterByName(result.Text, "IdA09");
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(paramA09))
                {
                    //await DisplayAlert("Scanned barcode", paramA09, "OK");

                    await SendPresenceAck(paramA09,sender,e); //, this.idPrestation);

                }
                else
                {
                    // Message d'erreur
                    await this.DisplayAlert("Attention", "Erreur de la validation d'un invité par QR Code.", "Cancel");


                }


                await Navigation.PopModalAsync(); //.PopAsync();


            });
        };

    }
```

And there is a method SendPresenceAck when I have scan a QrCode

```
  private async Task SendPresenceAck(string paramA09, object sender, EventArgs e) //, int? idPrestation)
    {

        int idParticipant;
        if (!int.TryParse(paramA09, out idParticipant))
        {
            //await this.ShowAlert("Attention", "Problème de lecture du QR Code.");
            await this.DisplayAlert("Attention", "Problème de lecture du QR Code.", "Yes","No");

            return;
        }

        // On appelle le WS pour signifier la présence
        // On passe par validateService
        // On prépare la validation de la présence
        var validateService = new ValidatePresenceService(this.Token);

        // On ajoute la ligne à valider
        var validate = validateService.AddNewPresence(idParticipant, this.idPrestation, true);

        // On déclenche l'envoi au WS (si besoin)
        if (validate != null)
        {
            // On envoie uniquement en cas de connexion
            if (!Global.GetSettingsBool(TypeSettings.IsHorsConnexion))
            {
                //await validateService.SendAll();
                // Attention : si participant déjà enregistré : erreur 403
                try
                {
                    await validateService.Send(await validate);
                    await this.DisplayAlert("OK", "Le billet est validé.", "OK");
                }
                catch (WebException ex)
                {
                    HttpWebResponse objresponse = ex.Response as HttpWebResponse;
                    if (objresponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)
                    {
                        // 403 : le participant a déjà été enregistré aujourd'hui
                        // Message d'erreur
                        await this.DisplayAlert("Attention", "Le billet a déjà été enregistré, le numéro du billet a déjà été scanné auparavant.", "Yes", "No");
                        return;
                    }
                    else if (objresponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
                    {
                        // 404 : billet non valide
                        var alert = await this.DisplayAlert("Attention", "Le billet n'est pas valide.", "Yes","No");
                        if (alert==true)
                        return;
                        else
                        {

                        }
                    }
                    else if (objresponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
                    {
                        // 401 : impossible d'identifier le numéro du billet
                       var alert =  await this.DisplayAlert("Attention", "Impossible d'identifier le numéro du billet, veuillez vérifier les informations de celui ci.", "Yes", "No");
                        if (alert==true)
                        return;
                        else
                        {
                            Debug.WriteLine(alert);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception exception)
                {
                    // Erreur
                    await this.DisplayAlert("Attention", exception.Message, "Yes", "No");
                    return;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Hors connexion : on vérifie juste si l'utilisateur n'est pas déjà présent dans la table SQL

                // Attention : si pas de prestation : on a le droit d'enregistrer plusieurs fois la présence
                // Si il y a une prestation, en revanche, on doit vérifier qu'il n'est pas déjà inscrit

                if (validate.Result.IdPrestation.HasValue &&
                    validateService.IsInscriptionAlreadyRecorded(await validate))
                {
                    // Déjà trouvé : message d'erreur
                    await this.DisplayAlert("Attention", "Le participant a déjà été enregistré.", "Yes", "No");

                    return;
                }

            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Pb à l'insertion des données ??

        }


        //return;

        await BtnScanClicked(sender, e);
    }
```

So I want, on my scan to click on a button to return on a scan for scan an other QrCode. A sort of a button "do you want scan an other time?"

Edit: For the moment the only important message is `"await this.DisplayAlert("Attention", "Problème de lecture du QR Code.", "Yes","No");

In English ("Alert", Problem to read QR Code." "Yes", "No");

I try to call again at the end of the SendPresenceAck function but it doesn't work.
For the moment if you answer "yes" or "no" it do nothing. I want to return on scan if you answer "yes" and return to the page if you answer "no".

Answer (score 1):

Might need to see more code, but you are always popping your scanner page at the end of the `OnScanResult` by calling:

```
await Navigation.PopModalAsync();
```

at the end of the `OnScanResult` method, so no matter what you do in `SendPresenceAck` when you return from that method, you are popping the modal scanner page.

The non-english (french?) text makes it hard for me to know which alert is asking if the user wants to scan another code, but regardless no matter what they respond, the page will be popped.

Oh, wait, it looks like you have some recursion going on? i.e. `BtnScanClicked` calls `SendPresenceAck` and `SendPresenceAck` calls `BtnScanClicked` at the end... I'd have to dig though all of your logic to see if this may be an issue, but again that is hard because of the non-english language makes it hard for me to follow code flow after user responses to the multiple alerts.

Comment: So at the end of SendPresenceAck if i do `await Navigation.PopModalAsync()`. there is not problem with the ModalStack? Because, often, I have an out of range when i try to push or pop a page in the function SendPresenceAck.

Comment: If you would like a Xamarin support engineer to investigate further, I suggest you open a free support case. That way you can provide a complete project that shows the issue securely and privately. You can open a free Xamarin support case here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/getsupport?wf=0&tenant=classiccommercial&oaspworkflow=start_1.0.0.0&locale=en-us&supportregion=en-us&pesid=16068&forceorigin=esmc&ccsid=636645150473349054